# WPF : Update View Model when DB Changes (Concurrency Issue)

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm, database-concurrency

I'm currently working on WPF app that is architectured as follows:

- MVVM
- Entity Framwork 4 (with LINQ).
- WCF service that pool Database to get data (Oracle).
- I Make my WFC call in my View Model Class and put my data in an ObsevableCollections.
- Db Changes occurs from a another app.

So my app does not do any write actions on the DB what-so-ever (Zéro), it only reads data and displays it on the UI.

How can I make my app to be quickly responsive to DB changes, I read about the following solutions but I'm confused and don't know what to use:

- Pooling DB every n seconds with a DispatcherTimer (seems to be too much work cause data changes every millisecond)
- SqlDependency, searched all over the internet but didn't find a proper implementation with EF.

As I said, db changes every millisecond (financial data from other sources),

How can resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you see this example (SqlDependency + Entity Framework)... https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-SqlDependency-5c0da0b3

Comment: yes i did but coudnt get what i wanted from if... i think i found a suitable solution, i'll post it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### i tried the code bellow and it seemed to be working okay for the moment (but i still have some doubts about that infinit loop), let me know what you thing :

```
public class MyViewModel
    {


          BackgroundWorker _bgWorker ;
          //some props
          //some funcs


protected internal MyViewModel(Session session)
        {
            Session = session;
            RefreshData();
        }        

protected void RefreshData()
        {
            try
            {
                _bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker
                {
                    WorkerReportsProgress = true,
                    WorkerSupportsCancellation = true

                };
                _bgWorker.DoWork += bgDoWork;

                if (!_bgWorker.IsBusy)
                {
                    _bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _bgWorker.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

        private void bgDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
            while (!worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                //Thread.Sleep(1000); should i keep this or not ?
                Proxy(); // WCF calls
            }
        }
        }
```